# How do I include Groovy Extension methods in jar?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, extension-methods, maven-publish

I have a groovy library that I publish as a jar file on a nexus repository. When I use extension methods in the library from another project's Gradle script, I get a *MissingMethodException*.

As a reference, say I have a String extension method, such as:

```
static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String self, String str) {
    self.toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())
}
```

If in my library I call the method using `"foobar".containsIgnoreCase("Foo")`, I will get the exception. If I instead call it using `StringExtensions.containsIgnoreCase("foobar", "Foo")`, it works, no problem.

My guess is that this is an issue with publishing the Groovy project without the META-INF file that defines the extensions. Here is the project structure:

```
- Library
  - src/main/
    - groovy/ 
      - (here are my sources)
    - resources/META-INF/groovy
      - org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule (contains details about my extension classes)
```

My ExtensionModule file looks like this:

```
moduleName=string-extensions
moduleVersion=1.0
extensionClasses=com.my.project.StringExtensions
```

In my publish block in *build.gradle*, I use the following:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

//...

sourceSets {
    main.groovy.outputDir = sourceSets.main.java.outputDir
    test.groovy.outputDir = sourceSets.test.java.outputDir
}

//...

publishing {

    publications {
        library(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

What do I need to include in my publication in order to get the extension methods correctly registered when I use this library in another project's Gradle build script? I have added the classpath/repo url for the dependency in my buildscript, and can access methods of the library - these just fail when calling an extension method.

Comment: What does your org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule file look like?  And have you checked that it has been included in the published jar file?

Comment: could you please show how and where you want to use this extension?

Comment: @emilies I added the contents.

Comment: @daggett this is shown near the top. Essentially, I call a method of the plugin, which in-turn calls its own extension method.

Comment: @Phil, do you want to use it inside gradle or inside the code that gradle builds?

Comment: @daggett inside gradle. i want the gradle classpath to correctly register the extension methods.

Comment: how have you tried to add extension to the gradle classpath (it's just not to repeat false way)

Comment: @daggett it is in my buildscript dependencies - `buildscript { repositories { ... } dependencies { classpath 'com.myproject:library:+' }}`

Comment: you could define ext methods using metaclass. or ectensionmodule is principal?

Answer (score 1):

Bad news: there is [a bug in Gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2973) because of which Gradle build scripts don’t support Groovy extension modules at the moment.

**One thing to note:** [the Groovy docs](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#module-descriptor) seem to be wrong in that they specify to put the module descriptor under `META-INF/groovy/`. When I do that, I can’t even use the extension method of the resulting library in a plain Groovy application. I had to put the descriptor under **`META-INF/services/`** instead to make it work.

That still doesn’t help with the Gradle use case. However, it shows that building and publishing works correctly: FWIW, I’ve just set up two tiny projects myself and I can reproduce the issue that you’re seeing (with Gradle 6.7.1). With the mentioned switch to the `META-INF/services/` directory, I could at least get the extension to work in a Groovy application. So, given that you can access the Groovy methods as non-extension methods in your Gradle build, looking at the rest of your question and by switching to `META-INF/services/`, I would suppose that your build incl. the publication should be configured correctly, too.

#### Minimal Reproducer Projects

The following two minimal reproducer projects show that the publication works, that the library can be used in a Groovy application and that it fails in a Gradle build. Gradle Wrapper files are not shown.

```
├── my_extension_lib
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── groovy
│           │   └── MyExtension.groovy
│           └── resources
│               └── META-INF
│                   └── services
│                       └── org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule
└── my_groovy_app
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src
        └── main
            └── groovy
                └── Test.groovy
```

First run `./gradlew publish` under `my_extension_lib/`. Then run `./gradlew run` under `my_groovy_app`.

`my_extension_lib/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        library(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'test'
            url = 'file:///tmp/my_test_repo'
        }
    }
}
```

`my_extension_lib/src/main/groovy/MyExtension.groovy`

```
class MyExtension {

    static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String self, String str) {
        self.toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())
    }
}
```

`my_extension_lib/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule`

```
moduleName=My Test
moduleVersion=1.0
extensionClasses=MyExtension
```

`my_groovy_app/build.gradle`

```
/* Test extension in Gradle */
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = 'file:///tmp/my_test_repo'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example:my_extension_lib:1.0'
    }
}

// works, i.e., the publication is ok
println(MyExtension.containsIgnoreCase("foobar", "Foo"))
// doesn’t work due to Gradle bug
//println("foobar".containsIgnoreCase('Foo'))


/* Test extension in Groovy application */

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'

application {
    mainClass = 'Test'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url = 'file:///tmp/my_test_repo'
    }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
    implementation 'com.example:my_extension_lib:1.0'
}
```

`my_groovy_app/src/main/groovy/Test.groovy`

```
class Test {

  static void main(String... args) {
      // works, i.e., extension library JAR was published correctly
      println("foobar".containsIgnoreCase('Foo'))
  }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this defect (I am one of the contributors on it), however I am interested in the solution. I believe that this is likely an issue with publication, not an actual issue with Gradle. Since there are no comments from Gradle contributors on the bug, I am hoping that it is user error, not an actual defect. Have you ensured the extension file is published with your plugin?

Comment: Three commentators on that ticket – melix, blindpirate and eskatos – are Gradle members. Given that they haven’t closed the ticket or commented negatively, I’d say they’ve acknowledged the bug. That also aligns with my further testing, see also my updated answer. Let me know if more details on the answer would be helpful, like a minimal reproducer showing that the publication works and can successfully be used at least in a Groovy project.

Comment: can you include the link to your project(s) mentioned above, or show details of you implementation if they differ from mine?

Comment: I’ve added the minimal reproducer projects to my answer.

Comment: thank you for this thorough walk-through!

Answer (score 1):

not really and answer - just another portion of information.

**groovy version 2.5+** takes care about both: `META-INF/services` and `META-INF/groovy`

link: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/1c358e84e427b3a6ff808533a93e1d76f4fa0d67/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/m12n/ExtensionModuleScanner.java#L42

**before groovy 2.5** only `META-INF/services` was processed

groovy scans resources named `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule` only once when statically creating MetaClassRegistry singleton in GroovySystem.java

link: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/1c358e84e427b3a6ff808533a93e1d76f4fa0d67/src/main/java/groovy/lang/GroovySystem.java#L37

---

to implement it somehow using this approach check how it's done in GrapeIvy.groovy class

link: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/1c358e84e427b3a6ff808533a93e1d76f4fa0d67/src/main/groovy/groovy/grape/GrapeIvy.groovy#L292

---

I think it's much easier to create a plugin for gradle and use metaClass to define custom methods

```
String.metaClass.up={ delegate.toUpperCase() }


task x{
    doLast{
        println( "hello".up() )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Hopefully they will address the defect soon. It is unfortunate that even Apache is looking for work-arounds for this issue in enterprise tools. Since I am the author of the library, I don't need to go this route. This definitely provides some great insight though!